# How to scroll li in list menu channel jquery

Tags: jquery

I need help please

how can I scroll channel tv in a list with jquery like programme tv

this is my html

```
<ul class="itemchannele">
            <li class="channele channeleselect">Guess With Jess</li>
            <li class="channele">Fun With Claude</li>
            <li class="channele">Sesame Street</li>
            <li class="channele"> Bear In The Big Blue House</li>
            <li class="channele">Boom And Reds</li>
            <li class="channele">The Hoobs</li>
            <li class="channele">Dirtgirlworld</li>
            <li class="channele">Timmy Time</li>
            <li class="channele">Pingu</li>
            <li class="channele">Miffy And Friends</li>
            <li class="channele">Penelope</li> 
            <li class="channele">Willa’s Wild Life</li>
            <li class="channele">Pinky Dinky Doo</li>
            <li class="channele">64 Zoo Lane</li>
            <li class="channele">Rupert Bear: Follow The Magic</li>
</ul>
```

for css code

```
      .itemchannele{
         height: 402px;
         margin: 0;
         overflow: auto;
         padding: 0 0 0 20px
      }
```

jquery I need example please without plugin just jquery

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/).
Let`s say that in element is stored your ul, so:

```
element.scrollTop(500);
```

you will scroll 500px from top of element.

With this:

```
element.scrollTop(some_li_in_ul.position().top);
```

you will scroll to position of li in element.

The [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method find position of element relative to his offset parent. And with .position().top you will get distance between top of li and start of his ul.

Example:

```
$('ul.itemchannele li:eq(15)').position().top;
```

Will find you ul, his 16th li ([.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) starts at zero), than top position of this li.